# Insert into local table from Linked Table query is slow

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I am trying to figure out a way to fasten insert query in Access Db.

I have a linked Table called QUADReportSource in Access db, which  is connected to spreadsheet called QUAD_report in my C drive. I am trying to copy 2 columns called Outlet and Agent Type from QUADReportSource  and insert into local table called TblTempQuad.

QUADReportSource has duplicate records (same outlet number with different Agent Type), so while inserting I am ensuring only unique combinations of[Outlet, Agent Type] are inserted into local table by making Outlet and Agent Type columns of TblTempQuad primary key.

QUADReportSource  has 332024 records. Inserting all 332024 takes 3 min, I am hoping unique records insertion into TblTempQuad should take less but its taking 5-6 min. Same result when I use distinct keyword in select query instead primary key.

**Here is the query :**

```
db.Execute "insert into TblTempQuad([Outlet],[Agent Type]) select [Outlet],[Agent Type] from QUADReportSource"
```

Comment: Access, SQL Server and MySQL are all different RDBMS. Try not to tag ones that aren't relevant to your question, please.

Comment: I wouldn't call that slow at all. It's usual for a `SELECT DISTINCT` to take more time, because filtering takes time too.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, That's a relief to hear. I thought I was doing something wrong. I do need your input on other thing. I have a form on Access that takes Outlet and Agent type fields from local table TblTempQUAD.  Is there a way I can do this insertion into local table before user opens the form?. Currently this happens as soon as user log- ins which means user has to wait for 5 min before using the form.

Comment: Eh...that's a separate question, and Access can't predict if a user is going to open a form. You can run queries asynchronously (perhaps as soon as the database is opened), but then you need to check if the query has completed.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, Yea currently I am calling this code on form click. Thanks for input

Answer (score 0):

I think SQL should be pretty fast, and definitely faster than looping through records using VBA, but what about acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet?  Here is an example.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "importTable", "C:\test\test.xlsx", ", True
```

I don't know what this has to do with SQL Server.